# How to restrict firefox browser to load media files?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon, webbrowser-control

I am using Firefox browser and my internet speed is not so good and i use to open so many tabs in the same browser and It takes too much time to load the page due to the media file (Images, videos and audios). Now i want the browser do not load these media files to browse faster.

**IS THAT POSSIBLE TO RESTRICT THE BROWSER ????**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another method can be used.. use extension 
"picture blocker"
The popular "picture Blocker" extension adds a toggle button to Firefox for example that switches the image loading state each time you activate it.